# "Make good" and "federal bench"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/biden-sign-executive-order-supreme-112225736.html), there is a line,

> President Joe Biden signed an executive order on Friday empaneling a commission to examine possible reforms to the Supreme Court and federal judiciary, **making good on a campaign trail promise sparked by his predecessor's tilting of the federal bench**

## Question 1

What does "make good" mean from the [**following definitions**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-good)?

1. > If you **make good** some damage, a loss, or a debt, you try to repair the damage, replace what has been lost, or repay the debt.
2. > If someone **makes good** a threat or promise or makes good on it, they do what they have threatened or promised to do.
3. > If someone **makes good,** they become successful, famous, or rich.

I guess without any support here make good would mean by 2?

## Question 2

What does **federal bench** mean here?

Would that mean possibly the line of judges changed by the former president Trump here?

Comment: Both your intuitions are exactly correct.

Comment: @randomhead Thank you. Now anybody is free for bounty by making answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> making good on a campaign trail promise sparked by his predecessor's tilting of the federal bench

Your interpretations are fine.  'Make good' is defined in one dictionary as follows.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-good

> If someone makes good a threat or promise or makes good on it, they do what they have threatened or promised to do.